# Differences between normal chessbase and chessbase Steam

Tags: engines, software, database, chessbase, study

I just recently realised that the chessbase software is available on Steam, which would seem normal to me if it wasn't almost half the price compared to the version on the official website. I have chessbase 16 and chessbase 17 is on offer but I don't want to pay for a cut-down version, do you know if there is a difference?

Comment: And what, more precisely, do you consider 'normal ChessBase'?  I find four CB17 offers from ChessBase, from the top Premium (500 Euro), which includes Mega 2023 database, CB magazine,  12 months CB account, online-DB and 'ducates' to the CB 17 (program-only; 150 Euro), with only the online-DB.  Which of those are you comparing against?  Or are you asking if CB 17 SE (steam edition) differs from CB 17 program-only?

Comment: The official chessbase website offers from the program itself to the database packages, in the case of the steam version it only sells you the program, even so the price varies by 50%. I would just like to know if the program from the chessbase website to the Steam version has variations beyond the databases, such as removed options like for example the option to rate with medals. In short, the databases do not concern me, those can be purchased separately, my question is with the options offered by the software itself.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is not much of anything unless you are a power user. I do believe there are issues if you intend to use things like the Mega Database etc. ultimately it's just a licensing thing.

In all honesty I wouldn't generally recommend Chessbase. This is from someone who owns it, uses it extensively, has a dedicated server just doing analysis.

There is nothing in Chessbase that something like SCID cannot do for average user.

Comment: Thank you very much, so it is understood that the difference is only in the databases. By the way, I love Scid but I have changed my computer to an Hp with windows 11 and it doesn't accept the Scid program. It downloads but gives me an error when I run it, so for the moment I only use Chessbase.

Comment: @lixuezhao https://scid.sourceforge.net/. Seems to work for me. Also just because it's a windows PC doesn't mean you can't install your favourite Linux distro ;)